# How do I remove IIS custom header using Powershell?

Tags: iis, powershell, iis-7

I am writing a powershell script that deploys a website to IIS 7.  I would like to do the following command to remove a custom header using the Web-Administration module in powershell rather than with appcmd.  How do I do this command in powershell not using appcmd?

```
appcmd set config /section:httpProtocol /-customHeaders.[name='X-Powered-By']
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To remove the header on iis level:

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST  
                                -Filter system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders 
                                -Name . 
                                -AtElement @{name='X-Powered-By'}
```

And for a specific site:

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'
                                -Filter system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders
                                -Name .
                                -AtElement @{name='X-Powered-By'}
```

Comment: can you comment on how to add a customHeader using the Add-WebconfigurationProperty?  I've been at it quite a while and finally stumbled across your answer here.

Comment: @MikeDevenney the following command will add the key value pair X-NODE, 1 to the response headers on the box

Add-WebConfigurationProperty  -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter 'system.WebServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders' -Name . -Value @{name='X-NODE'; value='1'}

Comment: @Tedford Thanks!  So would the proper approach for adding a header to every site in IIS be to iterate over the sites collection and run the Add-WebConfigurationProperty for each one?

Comment: Shay, how do I remove other "system" headers via powershell? Q is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40776387/147637

Answer (score 2):

### Adding a new custom field eg. `xff-ip` to have remote client ip from `x-forwarded-for` request header

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults/logFile/customFields" -name "." -value @{logFieldName='xff-ip';sourceName='X-FORWARDED-FOR';sourceType='RequestHeader'}
```

Or for a specific site:

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='My Super Site']/logFile/customFields"  -name "." -value @{logFieldName='xff-ip';sourceName='X-FORWARDED-FOR';sourceType='RequestHeader'}
```

### Removing your added custom logging field eg.`xff-ip`

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults/logFile/customFields" -name "."  -AtElement @{logFieldName='xff-ip'}
```

Or from your site only

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='My Super Site']/logFile/customFields"  -name "." -AtElement @{logFieldName='xff-ip'}
```