# How to remove non-IIS , OS source headers via powershell?

Tags: powershell, iis

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/18152186/147637, there is a nice example how to use powershell to remove the X-Powered-By header. That works great.

How do I , in powershell, suppress these addl headers:

- Server
- X-AspNet-Version
- and the other X-Powered-By  (X-Powered-By: UrlRewriter.NET 2.0.0)

> ```
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
> X-Powered-By: UrlRewriter.NET 2.0.0
> X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“X-Powered-By:” is actually inherited from the IIS root configuration.The script to remove the “X-Powered-By” header assumes you have Powershell and the Web Server (IIS) Administration Cmdlets installed and figure out the correct incantations.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration;
Clear-WebConfiguration "/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders/add[@name='X-Powered-By']"
```

For Further help, you can refer https://www.troyhunt.com/shhh-dont-let-your-response-headers/

Comment: Radadip, is your proposal specific to the X-Powered-By mentioned in the OP?  I already do "Remove-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST -Filter system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders -Name . -AtElement @{name='X-Powered-By'}"  -- does your command affect a diff header?

Comment: • Server: The web server software being run by the site. Typical examples include “Microsoft-IIS/7.5”, “nginx/1.0.11” and “Apache”.
• X-Powered-By: The collection (there can be multiple) of application frameworks being run by the site. Typical examples include: “ASP.NET”, “PHP/5.2.17” and “UrlRewriter.NET 2.0.0”.
• X-AspNet-Version: Obviously an ASP.NET only header, typical examples include “2.0.50727”, “4.0.30319” and “1.1.4322”.
• X-AspNetMvc-Version: Again, you’ll only see this in the ASP.NET stack and typical examples include “3.0”, “2.0” and “1.0”.

Comment: I am talking about the above mentioned bullet pointed Headers.

Answer (score 2):

To hide "X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319" use

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT'  -Filter "system.web/httpRuntime" -name "enableVersionHeader" -value "False"
```

To remove "X-Powered-By" use

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST" -Filter "system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders" -Name . -AtElement @{name='X-Powered-By'}
```